# Concatenating string with space

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, linestring, concatenation

I am adding a number of strings together to create a linestring but as such I need spaces between the initial XY values and the end XY values, plus a comma in between the two halves.

Should result in LINESTRING(97763.88319  434314.9609 , 97620.90369  434175.115)
but the space is not recognized like it would be in excel
I don't want to make another attribute which only holds a space to then include it as a variable.

This is the expression I used:

concat("LINESTRING(", "X", " ", "Y", " , ", "newX", " " , "newY")

[image: Field calculator]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use single-quote (`'`) for hardcoded strings and double-quote (`"`) for fields reference:

Try with that:

`concat('LINESTRING(', "X", "Y", ' , ' , "new_X", "new_Y", ')')`

Comment: @nashm999 - Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side =)